# HDF5 package Ian's compression

Tags: julia

Would anyone know if the HDF5 package maintained by Tim Holy can handle compression (zlib, bzip2, Lzo, etc.) ? Couldn't find anything in the documentation - https://github.com/timholy/HDF5.jl . If yes, can you point me out to any examples. Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You admittedly have to read the README quite carefully, but there is a link to the `doc/` directory which contains much more detail. The short answer is, yes, it does support compression.

I'll make that link more prominent now.

Comment: Thanks, Tim. Yes, I do admit I didn't read the README carefully.

Comment: quick question (i'm a newbie to HDF5) - I did see that three is a `compress` option - can you share with me which algo is used for compression, i.e. zlib, bzip2, lzo, etc.?